# How to add logic to an AWS load balancer to forward request to specific cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I'm currently trying to add some logic in my AWS LB to forward a request to different clusters depending on one of the headers passed to the request, but I only managed to find a way with a redirect. Since for a forwarding I need to use a target group (which is already used at the moment).

I was thinking about using a lambda function, but I didn't really find a way to have it in front of the LB in a clean way.

Here what it should look like

`service.us.domain.com`: US load balancer
`service.eu.domain.com`: EU load balancer
`service.domain.com`: US or EU load balancer depending on the header

Any solution involving other AWS solutions are also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

If you're trying to forward to a specific load balancer based on location (such as US or EU) I would suggest looking at Route 53.

You could use either one of the following:

- If it is simply down to latency then you can use a [latency rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-latency) that will forward to the load balancer based on user latency.
- If it is down to a targeted content requirement or legal requirement you could use a [geolocation rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo).

For either of these rules the domain name would need to be the same.

**Original**

You can do this using a single Application Load Balancer as long as each pool of servers has its own target group.

When you create a listener it will have a default rule, ensure this goes to the default target group. Once you have done this you can add a additional rule to the listener if a specific header and value are passed in, this would forward to your target group.

More information on this approach is available on the [Advanced Request Routing for AWS Application Load Balancers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-advanced-request-routing-for-aws-application-load-balancers/) post.

If this functionality is not enough for your use case an alternative would be to add a CloudFront distribution in front of your load balancer. Then add a [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) function as a origin request event, this would dynamically change the origin based on your own defined logic.

Some example functions are available on the [Lambda@Edge Example Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html) page.

Comment: Ok I guess I won't have a solution without using a cloudfront distribution for a lambda function in front of it. I was trying to avoid that but thanks anyway.

Comment: I have updated answer with a Route 53 suggestion as I saw you amended question, not sure if this will work for your scenario?

Comment: No I cannot use the latency or geolocation solution, because the forwarding will be depending on a tenant name, so it will entirely depend on a list I'll need to check for that. There is still some logic to put somewhere.

Comment: Ah lambda@edge it is then :)